# Android App that tells which of my other apps are hogging the connection

Tags: android, network-monitor

I'm looking for an app that tells me which of my other apps in my smartphone uses up most of the bandwidth (aside: Is bandwidth the appropriate term to use here?).

Background: My laptop connects to the internet through my smartphone. This has worked fine for quite some time now. But recently, a few minutes after phone screen turns off my ping shoots up from <100ms up to the point that it times out. This has happened once before and I've managed to pinpoint the culprit as Google Photos' auto-upload. The process consisted of a lot of trial and error, and was very time consuming. I need to figure out which one's the culprit this time. Any recommendations?

I'm sure it's the phone and not the laptop because:

- Going idle triggers the spike in ping
- Clearing RAM and unlocking the phone brings back the ping to <100ms

Comment: I haven't had this kind of problem, so I cannot name "the correct tool". But taking a look into my list of [apps for network diagnosis](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_diagnosis#group_374) should narrow down things – while waiting for the "perfect answer" ;)